# webpack CSS-loader should only load files in a specific folder

Tags: webpack, css-loader

I could not find any information about how to configure the CSS-loader module via webpack that it will only import files in a specific folder.
Is there any way to achieve this?

I am using webpack 5.4.

My rules-configuration looks like this:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/i,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
}
```

Any input is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try the `include` [option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition), for example:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/i,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'specific-folder')
}
```

Comment: intresting, thx i will look into it! Is __dirname equals to project rootpath?

Comment: The directory name of the current module. See https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

Comment: I will try this out ASAP, but most probably this is the solution :) will mark the answer as correct once i tested

Comment: this actually didnt work, files were still included outside the project